# Undefined al devolver Array desde Método

Tags: nodejs, array, object

Tengo el siguiente código:

Método que llama:

```
 jSReturn = parsear(path);
 console.log("despues de llamar");
 console.log(jSReturn);
```

Método parsear:

```
    var input = fs.readFileSync(path);
var fileContents = fs.readFileSync(path,'ucs2');
parser.parseString(fileContents, function (err, result) {
    console.log("se ha parseado el XML");
    var libxml = require("libxmljs");
    var xmlDoc = libxml.parseXmlString(fileContents);
    var varXML = xmlDoc.root().childNodes();
    var JSONreturn = [];
    for(var i=1; i<varXML.length; i++){
        //El primero lo ignoramos porque es datos de ultima actualización
        var varBucle = varXML[i];
        var varObjeto = getJSONFromParking(varBucle);
        JSONreturn.push(varObjeto);
    }
    console.log("Desde el metodo" + JSONreturn);
    return JSONreturn;
});
```

El log obtenido es el siguiente:

```
desde el main
vamos a parsear el xml
se ha parseado el XML
Desde el metodo[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
despues de llamar
undefined
```

Desde el método parsear lo hace bien, pero al hacer el return se pierde la referencia y muestra undefinded.
¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Lo que me extraña es que no te dé ningún error definiendo una variable con la palabra reservada "var". Yo lo primero que haría es cambiar el nombre de esa variable.

Comment: Lo he puesto para la explicación, voy a editarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás confundiendo el valor de retorno de `parsear()` con el valor de retorno del callback asíncrono de `parse.parseString()`.

Si usas un método asíncrono, difícilmente vas a poder devolver valores de manera síncrona. Usa callbacks "all the way", o devuelve `Promise`s.

Comment: Gracias por responder. He probado con un callback y me ha funcionado.